# Define HGlobal in JNA

Tags: java, c++, jna

I have to translate app from C++ to Java, but it uses dll, so I have to use JNA. Application should scan something from device. Here is app in C++:

```
//HEADERS
ABC_Shell = (int (*)(char* cmd, int len, char* rsp, int buflen))GetProcAddress(g_hLib, "ABC_Shell");
ABC_ImageProcessFromRaw = (int (*)(HGLOBAL hFront, HGLOBAL hRear))GetProcAddress(g_hLib, "ABC_ImageProcessFromRaw");
//END    

HGLOBAL hImage[3];
memset(hImage, 0, sizeof(hImage));

nRet = ABC_Shell("CP12", strlen(szShell), (char*)hImage, sizeof(hImage));
ABC_ImageProcessFromRaw(hImage[0], hImage[1]);  //FACE, BACK RGB IMAGE
ABC_ImageProcessFromRaw(hImage[2], NULL);       //FACE IR IMAGE
SaveImage(0, hImage[0], hImage[1], hImage[2]);
```

And here is in Java:

```
//HEADERS
int ABC_Shell(String command, int len, byte[] response, int buflen);
int ABC_ImageProcessFromRaw(byte[] hFront, byte[] hRear);
//END

byte[] response = new byte[64];
api.ABC_Shell("CP12", 8, response, 1024);  // it works, but response is strange
api.ABC_ImageProcessFromRaw(response, null);
```

Of course device is scanning, but I don't know what kind of variable use to take a response and after that use it in next function. In C++ is HGlobal[3], there is no something like that in JNA. I was looking here - https://jna.java.net/javadoc/platform/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/W32API.html.

Do you have any ideas, how to handle this global memory block in three parts?

Comment: For reference C != C++.  Your native code appears to be straight C.

Comment: At some point in your headers there's a `typedef` which defines what `HGLOBAL` actually means (e.g. `typedef void* HGLOBAL;`).  Find that and include it in your question.  Most likely you can just pretend it's an opaque pointer and use JNA's `Pointer`.  JNA will handle an array of `Pointer` just fine (e.g. `Pointer[] hImage = new Pointer[3];`).

Comment: @technomage Sadly, there is no something like "typedef ... HGLOBAL;". I was already think about it.

Pointer[] is not working. Pointer[0] is filling, but others are still null and still "ImageProcessFromRaw" returns 0 instead of 1(success). What do you think about PointerByReference? Might it work?

Comment: This appears to be a w32 API definition, `typedef HANDLE HGLOBAL;`.  So it's just a `Pointer`.  Update your question to reflect your changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
int ABC_Shell(String command, int len, Pointer[] response, int buflen);
int ABC_ImageProcessFromRaw(Pointer hFront, Pointer hRear);
...

Pointer[] response = new Pointer[3];
// You should probably be more programmatic about the command buffer and its length
api.ABC_Shell("CP12", 8, response, response.length * Pointer.SIZE);
api.ABC_ImageProcessFromRaw(response[0], null);
```

Answer (score 2):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx

typedef HANDLE HGLOBAL;

HGLOBAL is same with HANDLE, so you can use W32API.HANDLE for HGLOBAL